# How to pass post data to another view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a 2 views : 1. index 2. PrintPax

the "index" view is where the form filtering data runs, it works perfectly because it gets the form's post data $month and $year.

When I want to pass this post data to the view "printPax" there's no data

this is my controller :

```
public function index() 
{
    $data['title'] = "Dashboard";
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['username' => $this->session->userdata('username')])->row_array();
    $data['countuser'] = $this->Admin_model->getCountUser();
    $data['onprogress'] = $this->Admin_model->getOnProgressPassanger();
    $data['pax'] = $this->Admin_model->getPax();
    $data['destination'] = $this->Datamaster_model->getAllDestination();
    $month = $this->input->post('month');
    $year = $this->input->post('year');

    $data['filter'] = $this->Admin_model->getFilterData($month, $year);
    if (!empty($this->input->post('month') && $this->input->post('year'))) {
        $data['filter'] = $this->Admin_model->getFilterData($month, $year);
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
}

public function printFilterData()
{
    $month = $this->input->get('month');
    $year = $this->input->get('year');

    $data['filter'] = $this->Admin_model->getFilterData($month, $year);
    if (!empty($this->input->get('month') && $this->input->get('year'))) {
        $data['filter'] = $this->Admin_model->getFilterData($month, $year);
    }

    $this->load->view('view_print/print_filterdata', $data);
}
```

and this is my model :

```
  public function getFilterData($month, $year)
{
    $query = "SELECT passanger.id, passanger.id_user, destination.destination, count(pax) as pax,user.name, passanger.date_tour 
              FROM passanger 
              INNER JOIN destination 
                ON passanger.destination = destination.id_destination 
              INNER JOIN user 
                ON passanger.id_user = user.id_user 
              WHERE MONTH(passanger.date_tour) = '$month' 
              AND YEAR(passanger.date_tour) = '$year' 
              GROUP BY destination, id_user ORDER BY date DESC";
    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
}
```

And I have a button to link the printPax view

```
<a href="<?= base_url('admin/printfilterdata') ?>" class="btn btn-danger">
Print
</a>
```

What I want is when I click the print button, that form filter data gets passed to the "printPax" view

Comment: do you get any data from your model? what does `print_r($data['filter']);die();` output? btw, why are you using this line: `$data['filter'] = $this->Admin_model->getFilterData($month, $year);` twice?

Comment: I still get the data if i post the input in index view, my bad i though its still work if its in index view

Comment: save any data you want to persist across pages/refreshes in a session variable

Comment: I see, after the input post save the input to the session then pass to the model ? Then when should i unset the session after i get the data ?